# C# AutoComplete

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I am trying to add an autocomplete feature to a textbox, the results are coming from a database. They come in the format of

> [001] Last, First Middle

Currently you must type [001]... to get the entries to show. **So the problem is that I want it to complete even if I type the firstname first**. So if an entry was

> [001] Smith, John D

if I started typing John then this entry should show up in the results for the auto complete.

Currently the code looks something like

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
txtBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsc;
txtBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest; 
txtBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; 

....

if (results.Rows.Count > 0)
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Rows.Count && i < 10; i++) 
    {
        row = results.Rows[i];
        acsc.Add(row["Details"].ToString());
    }
}
```

*results is a dataset containing the query results*

*The query is a simple search query using the like statement. The correct results are returned if we do not use the autocomplete and just toss the results into an array.*

Any advice?

**EDIT:**

Here is the query that returns the results

```
SELECT Name from view_customers where Details LIKE '{0}'
```

*With {0} being the placeholder for the searched string.*

Comment: It looks ok at a glance. It would be useful to see more of the code, including the query used and the initialization of 'id' (do you have two autocomplete boxes going?).

Comment: Ok added an edit with the query. I am only using 1 autocomplete box. The ID is actually not ever being used in the results it was added for later use and thus I have removed it in this edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There is a nice free c# [autocomplete control](http://code.google.com/p/email-autocomplete) available ([with source code](http://email-autocomplete.googlecode.com/svn/trunk)) that is easy to modify.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The existing AutoComplete functionality only supports searching by prefix. There doesn't seem to be any decent way to override the behavior.

Some people have implemented their own autocomplete functions by overriding the `OnTextChanged` event. That's probably your best bet.

For example, you can add a `ListBox` just below the `TextBox` and set its default visibility to false. Then you can use the `OnTextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ListBox` to display and select items.

This seems to work pretty well as a rudimentary example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    acsc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acsc;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    acsc.Add("[001] some kind of item");
    acsc.Add("[002] some other item");
    acsc.Add("[003] an orange");
    acsc.Add("[004] i like pickles");
}

void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
    hideResults();
    return;
    }

    foreach (String s in textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
    {
    if (s.Contains(textBox1.Text))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found text in: " + s);
        listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        listBox1.Visible = true;
    }
    }
}

void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    hideResults();
}

void listBox1_LostFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    hideResults();
}

void hideResults()
{
    listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

There's a lot more you could do without too much effort: append text to the text box, capture additional keyboard commands, and so forth.

Comment: Remember that this means the dropdown cannot overhang the form below the bottom edge of the window.

Comment: Ug. The reason I'm looking at this question is that I replaced a textbox/listbox solution in a user control, with a combo, as I had problems with it not being able to overhang the bottom of forms...

Answer (score 6):

If you decide to use a query that is based on user input make sure you use SqlParameters to avoid SQL Injection attacks

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name from view_customers where Details LIKE '%" + @SearchParam + "%'";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchParam", searchParam);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation that inherits the `ComboBox` control class, rather than replacing the whole combo-box with a new control. It displays its own drop-down when you type in the text box, but clicking to show the drop-list is handled as before (i.e. not with this code). As such you get that proper native control and look.

Please use it, modify it and edit the answer if you would like to improve it!

```
class ComboListMatcher : ComboBox, IMessageFilter
{
    private Control ComboParentForm; // Or use type "Form" 
    private ListBox listBoxChild;
    private int IgnoreTextChange;
    private bool MsgFilterActive = false;

    public ComboListMatcher()
    {
        // Set up all the events we need to handle
        TextChanged += ComboListMatcher_TextChanged;
        SelectionChangeCommitted += ComboListMatcher_SelectionChangeCommitted;
        LostFocus += ComboListMatcher_LostFocus;
        MouseDown += ComboListMatcher_MouseDown;
        HandleDestroyed += ComboListMatcher_HandleDestroyed;
    }

    void ComboListMatcher_HandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MsgFilterActive)
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    ~ComboListMatcher()
    {
    }

    private void ComboListMatcher_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HideTheList();
    }

    void ComboListMatcher_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxChild != null && !listBoxChild.Focused)
            HideTheList();
    }

    void ComboListMatcher_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IgnoreTextChange++;
    }

    void InitListControl()
    {
        if (listBoxChild == null)
        {
            // Find parent - or keep going up until you find the parent form
            ComboParentForm = this.Parent;

            if (ComboParentForm != null)
            {
                // Setup a messaage filter so we can listen to the keyboard
                if (!MsgFilterActive)
                {
                    Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
                    MsgFilterActive = true;
                }

                listBoxChild = listBoxChild = new ListBox();
                listBoxChild.Visible = false;
                listBoxChild.Click += listBox1_Click;
                ComboParentForm.Controls.Add(listBoxChild);
                ComboParentForm.Controls.SetChildIndex(listBoxChild, 0); // Put it at the front
            }
        }
    }


    void ComboListMatcher_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IgnoreTextChange > 0)
        {
            IgnoreTextChange = 0;
            return;
        }

        InitListControl();

        if (listBoxChild == null)
            return;

        string SearchText = this.Text;

        listBoxChild.Items.Clear();

        // Don't show the list when nothing has been typed
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            foreach (string Item in this.Items)
            {
                if (Item != null && Item.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    listBoxChild.Items.Add(Item);
            }
        }

        if (listBoxChild.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            Point PutItHere = new Point(this.Left, this.Bottom);
            Control TheControlToMove = this;

            PutItHere = this.Parent.PointToScreen(PutItHere);

            TheControlToMove = listBoxChild;
            PutItHere = ComboParentForm.PointToClient(PutItHere);

            TheControlToMove.Show();
            TheControlToMove.Left = PutItHere.X;
            TheControlToMove.Top = PutItHere.Y;
            TheControlToMove.Width = this.Width;

            int TotalItemHeight = listBoxChild.ItemHeight * (listBoxChild.Items.Count + 1);
            TheControlToMove.Height = Math.Min(ComboParentForm.ClientSize.Height - TheControlToMove.Top, TotalItemHeight);
        }
        else
            HideTheList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy the selection from the list-box into the combo box
    /// </summary>
    private void CopySelection()
    {
        if (listBoxChild.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            this.SelectedItem = listBoxChild.SelectedItem;
            HideTheList();
            this.SelectAll();
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ThisList = sender as ListBox;

        if (ThisList != null)
        {
            // Copy selection to the combo box
            CopySelection();
        }
    }

    private void HideTheList()
    {
        if (listBoxChild != null)
            listBoxChild.Hide();
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x201) // Mouse click: WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        {
            var Pos = new Point((int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF), (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16));

            var Ctrl = Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd);
            if (Ctrl != null)
            {
                // Convert the point into our parent control's coordinates ...
                Pos = ComboParentForm.PointToClient(Ctrl.PointToScreen(Pos));

                // ... because we need to hide the list if user clicks on something other than the list-box
                if (ComboParentForm != null)
                {
                    if (listBoxChild != null &&
                        (Pos.X < listBoxChild.Left || Pos.X > listBoxChild.Right || Pos.Y < listBoxChild.Top || Pos.Y > listBoxChild.Bottom))
                    {
                        this.HideTheList();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (m.Msg == 0x100) // WM_KEYDOWN
        {
            if (listBoxChild != null && listBoxChild.Visible)
            {
                switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case 0x1B: // Escape key
                        this.HideTheList();
                        return true;

                    case 0x26: // up key
                    case 0x28: // right key
                        // Change selection
                        int NewIx = listBoxChild.SelectedIndex + ((m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0x26) ? -1 : 1);

                        // Keep the index valid!
                        if (NewIx >= 0 && NewIx < listBoxChild.Items.Count)
                            listBoxChild.SelectedIndex = NewIx;
                        return true;

                    case 0x0D: // return (use the currently selected item)
                        CopySelection();
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not 'simply' inherit from ComboBox. It has a few issues: ```ComboParentForm = this.Parent();``` should probably be ```this.Parent;```, ```ContainsNoCase``` looks like a custom extension method, ```IntEx.Limit``` looks like a custom helper class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out - have updated accordingly. Is that clearer? - hope it helps/helped.

Comment: Thanks! That is the best implementation I've seen. I've found some issues in the code and also I have simplified it a little. https://yadi.sk/i/SCrni3ZlqzoKr

Comment: a)you need two using statements.  `using System.Windows.Forms;` and 
`using System.Drawing;`  one for e.g. ComboBox   and one for Point   b)  this line `if (Item != null && Item.Contains(SearchText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`  doesn't work, there is no Contains method that takes two arguments like that. There is Contains that takes one argument, a string. You can use   `if (Item != null && Item.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower()))` that might do  as you intended.

Comment: I have a rather ignorant question. How do you add to the list?

Comment: `listBoxChild.Items.Add()` ... this is omitted from the example because exactly how you want to expose that is up to you!

Answer (score 1):

THIS WILL GIVE YOU THE AUTOCOMPLETE BEHAVIOR YOU ARE LOOKING FOR.

The attached example is a complete working form, Just needs your data source, and bound column names.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class frmTestAutocomplete : Form
{

    private DataTable maoCompleteList; //the data table from your data source
    private string msDisplayCol = "name"; //displayed text
    private string msIDcol = "id"; //ID or primary key

    public frmTestAutocomplete(DataTable aoCompleteList, string sDisplayCol, string sIDcol)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        maoCompleteList = aoCompleteList
        maoCompleteList.CaseSensitive = false; //turn off case sensitivity for searching
        msDisplayCol = sDisplayCol;
        msIDcol = sIDcol;
    }

    private void frmTestAutocomplete_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            testCombo.DisplayMember = msDisplayCol;
            testCombo.ValueMember = msIDcol; 
            testCombo.DataSource = maoCompleteList;
            testCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += testCombo_SelectedIndexChanged;
            testCombo.KeyUp += testCombo_KeyUp; 

    }


    private void testCombo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //use keyUp event, as text changed traps too many other evengts.

        ComboBox oBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        string sBoxText = oBox.Text;

        DataRow[] oFilteredRows = maoCompleteList.Select(MC_DISPLAY_COL + " Like '%" + sBoxText + "%'");

        DataTable oFilteredDT = oFilteredRows.Length > 0
                                ? oFilteredRows.CopyToDataTable()
                                : maoCompleteList;

        //NOW THAT WE HAVE OUR FILTERED LIST, WE NEED TO RE-BIND IT WIHOUT CHANGING THE TEXT IN THE ComboBox.

        //1).UNREGISTER THE SELECTED EVENT BEFORE RE-BINDING, b/c IT TRIGGERS ON BIND.
        testCombo.SelectedIndexChanged -= testCombo_SelectedIndexChanged; //don't select on typing.
        oBox.DataSource = oFilteredDT; //2).rebind to filtered list.
        testCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += testCombo_SelectedIndexChanged;


        //3).show the user the new filtered list.
        oBox.DroppedDown = true; //do this before repainting the text, as it changes the dropdown text.

        //4).binding data source erases text, so now we need to put the user's text back,
        oBox.Text = sBoxText;
        oBox.SelectionStart = sBoxText.Length; //5). need to put the user's cursor back where it was.


    }

    private void testCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ComboBox oBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (oBox.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format(@"Item #{0} was selected.", oBox.SelectedValue));
        }
    }
}

//=====================================================================================================
//      code from frmTestAutocomplete.Designer.cs
//=====================================================================================================
partial class frmTestAutocomplete
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.testCombo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // testCombo
        // 
        this.testCombo.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.testCombo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 51);
        this.testCombo.Name = "testCombo";
        this.testCombo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(224, 21);
        this.testCombo.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // frmTestAutocomplete
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 273);
        this.Controls.Add(this.testCombo);
        this.Name = "frmTestAutocomplete";
        this.Text = "frmTestAutocomplete";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmTestAutocomplete_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox testCombo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running that query (with `{0}` being replaced by the string entered), you might need:

```
SELECT Name from view_customers where Details LIKE '%{0}%'
```

`LIKE` still needs the `%` character...  And yes, you should use parameters rather than trusting the user's input :)

Also, you seem to be returning the `Name` column, but querying on the `Details` column.  So if someone types in "John Smith", if that's not in the `Details` column you won't get what you want back.

Comment: I notice that you're selecting Name, but you're querying on Details - that's not the problem is it?

Comment: ah nope got me on the name changes when posting the question. I Just changed the names to make it easier to understand. Thought I was consistant but I will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

**Two methods were successful in the autoComplete textBox control with SQL:**

but you should do the following:

a- create new project

b- add Component class to project and delete component1.designer "according to the name you give to component class"

c- download ["Download sample - 144.82 KB"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AutoCompleteTextBoxAdv/AutoCompleteTextBoxSample.zip)
and open it and open AutoCompleteTextbox class from AutoCompleteTextbox.cs
d- select all as illustrated in the image and copy it to current component class

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSqCa.png

e- Final - run project and stop to view new AutoCompleteTextbox in toolBox.

Now you can add the following two method that you can use SQL with them

**1- in Form_Load**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {            
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;database=My_dataBase;integrated security=true");
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [my_table]", cn);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);

   List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
          myList.Add((string)row[0]);
       }

   autoCompleteTextbox1.AutoCompleteList = myList;
    }
```

**2- in TextChanged Event**

```
 private void autoCompleteTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
         SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;database=My_dataBase;integrated security=true");
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [my_table]", cn);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);

     List<string> myList = new List<string>();
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          myList.Add((string)row[0]);
        }

   autoCompleteTextbox2.AutoCompleteList = myList;

    }
```