# WinForms | C# | AutoComplete in the Middle of a Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I have a textbox that does autocompletion like so:

```
txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
```

It works, but only at the beginning of a textbox. I'd like autocomplete to kick in for any word the user is entering, at any position in the textbox.

Comment: then you will need to write that functionality

Comment: ah ok, so nothing baked in... just use OnTextChanged and write my own... thanks.

Comment: Know of any good articles about writing a custom autocomplete in C# for WinForms?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-autocomplete

Comment: @MitchWheat - Why don't you add your comment as an answer, if it is accepted ?

Answer (score 39):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TubeUploader
{
    public class AutoCompleteTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private ListBox _listBox;
        private bool _isAdded;
        private String[] _values;
        private String _formerValue = String.Empty;

        public AutoCompleteTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResetListBox();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            _listBox = new ListBox();
            KeyDown += this_KeyDown;
            KeyUp += this_KeyUp;
        }

        private void ShowListBox()
        {
            if (!_isAdded)
            {
                Parent.Controls.Add(_listBox);
                _listBox.Left = Left;
                _listBox.Top = Top + Height;
                _isAdded = true;
            }
            _listBox.Visible = true;
            _listBox.BringToFront();
        }

        private void ResetListBox()
        {
            _listBox.Visible = false;
        }

        private void this_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateListBox();
        }

        private void this_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Tab:
                    {
                        if (_listBox.Visible)
                        {
                            InsertWord((String)_listBox.SelectedItem);
                            ResetListBox();
                            _formerValue = Text;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case Keys.Down:
                    {
                        if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex < _listBox.Items.Count - 1))
                            _listBox.SelectedIndex++;

                        break;
                    }
                case Keys.Up:
                    {
                        if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex > 0))
                            _listBox.SelectedIndex--;

                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Tab:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateListBox()
        {
            if (Text == _formerValue) return;
            _formerValue = Text;
            String word = GetWord();

            if (_values != null && word.Length > 0)
            {
                String[] matches = Array.FindAll(_values,
                                                 x => (x.StartsWith(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !SelectedValues.Contains(x)));
                if (matches.Length > 0)
                {
                    ShowListBox();
                    _listBox.Items.Clear();
                    Array.ForEach(matches, x => _listBox.Items.Add(x));
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    _listBox.Height = 0;
                    _listBox.Width = 0;
                    Focus();
                    using (Graphics graphics = _listBox.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            _listBox.Height += _listBox.GetItemHeight(i);
                            // it item width is larger than the current one
                            // set it to the new max item width
                            // GetItemRectangle does not work for me
                            // we add a little extra space by using '_'
                            int itemWidth = (int)graphics.MeasureString(((String)_listBox.Items[i]) + "_", _listBox.Font).Width;
                            _listBox.Width = (_listBox.Width < itemWidth) ? itemWidth : _listBox.Width;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ResetListBox();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ResetListBox();
            }
        }

        private String GetWord()
        {
            String text = Text;
            int pos = SelectionStart;

            int posStart = text.LastIndexOf(' ', (pos < 1) ? 0 : pos - 1);
            posStart = (posStart == -1) ? 0 : posStart + 1;
            int posEnd = text.IndexOf(' ', pos);
            posEnd = (posEnd == -1) ? text.Length : posEnd;

            int length = ((posEnd - posStart) < 0) ? 0 : posEnd - posStart;

            return text.Substring(posStart, length);
        }

        private void InsertWord(String newTag)
        {
            String text = Text;
            int pos = SelectionStart;

            int posStart = text.LastIndexOf(' ', (pos < 1) ? 0 : pos - 1);
            posStart = (posStart == -1) ? 0 : posStart + 1;
            int posEnd = text.IndexOf(' ', pos);

            String firstPart = text.Substring(0, posStart) + newTag;
            String updatedText = firstPart + ((posEnd == -1) ? "" : text.Substring(posEnd, text.Length - posEnd));


            Text = updatedText;
            SelectionStart = firstPart.Length;
        }

        public String[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return _values;
            }
            set
            {
                _values = value;
            }
        }

        public List<String> SelectedValues
        {
            get
            {
                String[] result = Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                return new List<String>(result);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Sample Usage

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoComplete
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        private readonly String[] _values = { "one", "two", "three", "tree", "four", "fivee" };

        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // AutoComplete is our special textbox control on the form
            AutoComplete.Values = _values;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of working nicely with multiline textboxes.  (Be sure to set `AcceptsTab` to *true*, however.)  Incredibly useful!

Comment: You really deserve +1, and i would give you more if i could. I'm using your AutoCompleteTextBox in my open source project now and it's a great improvement for my user experience. Thank you!

Comment: The owner of this custom control code is Peter Holpar, posted in 2010: http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/multivalue-autocomplete-winforms-textbox-for-tagging/ The source code can be downloaded at: http://autocompletetexboxcs.codeplex.com/ Next time acknowledge someone's contribution and work if you care about programming. Don't forget to give credit even if it's a free open code, it's not plagiarism, but it's discourteous and rude.

Comment: @WhySoSerious - well, when posting i had in my mind that i got this snippet from internet, but i didn't had the source or else i have always acknowledged the source!

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the AutoComplete in TestForm function ?

Comment: It work like simple autocomplete not like sql like'%hello%'

Comment: Nice control, but it doesn't work with objects like textbox autocomplete does, how can i adapt it to work like that, any pointers?

Comment: Just a note for others, this doesn't seem to be the general purpose multiline autocomplete textbox I was looking for, as comments led me to believe. Still looking.

Answer (score 8):

I made a few changes to the solution proposed by @PaRiMaL RaJ because the list box was not being displayed when the text box was inside a UserControl that was not tall enough. Basically, instead of adding the list box to the parent of the text box, I added to the form and I calculate the absolute position in the form.

```
public class AutoCompleteTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private ListBox _listBox;
        private bool _isAdded;
        private String[] _values;
        private String _formerValue = String.Empty;

        public AutoCompleteTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ResetListBox();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            _listBox = new ListBox();
            this.KeyDown += this_KeyDown;
            this.KeyUp += this_KeyUp;
        }

        private void ShowListBox()
        {
            if (!_isAdded)
            {
                Form parentForm = this.FindForm(); // new line added
                parentForm.Controls.Add(_listBox); // adds it to the form
                Point positionOnForm = parentForm.PointToClient(this.Parent.PointToScreen(this.Location)); // absolute position in the form
                _listBox.Left = positionOnForm.X;
                _listBox.Top = positionOnForm.Y + Height;
                _isAdded = true;
            }
            _listBox.Visible = true;
            _listBox.BringToFront();
        }



        private void ResetListBox()
        {
            _listBox.Visible = false;
        }

        private void this_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateListBox();
        }

        private void this_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Enter:
                case Keys.Tab:
                    {
                        if (_listBox.Visible)
                        {
                            Text = _listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                            ResetListBox();
                            _formerValue = Text;
                            this.Select(this.Text.Length, 0);
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case Keys.Down:
                    {
                        if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex < _listBox.Items.Count - 1))
                            _listBox.SelectedIndex++;
                        e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case Keys.Up:
                    {
                        if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex > 0))
                            _listBox.SelectedIndex--;
                        e.Handled = true;
                        break;
                    }


            }
        }

        protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Tab:
                    if (_listBox.Visible)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                default:
                    return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateListBox()
        {
            if (Text == _formerValue)
                return;

            _formerValue = this.Text;
            string word = this.Text;

            if (_values != null && word.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] matches = Array.FindAll(_values,
                                                 x => (x.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower())));
                if (matches.Length > 0)
                {
                    ShowListBox();
                    _listBox.BeginUpdate();
                    _listBox.Items.Clear();
                    Array.ForEach(matches, x => _listBox.Items.Add(x));
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    _listBox.Height = 0;
                    _listBox.Width = 0;
                    Focus();
                    using (Graphics graphics = _listBox.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i < 20)
                                _listBox.Height += _listBox.GetItemHeight(i);
                            // it item width is larger than the current one
                            // set it to the new max item width
                            // GetItemRectangle does not work for me
                            // we add a little extra space by using '_'
                            int itemWidth = (int)graphics.MeasureString(((string)_listBox.Items[i]) + "_", _listBox.Font).Width;
                            _listBox.Width = (_listBox.Width < itemWidth) ? itemWidth : this.Width; ;
                        }
                    }
                    _listBox.EndUpdate();
                }
                else
                {
                    ResetListBox();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ResetListBox();
            }
        }

        public String[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return _values;
            }
            set
            {
                _values = value;
            }
        }

        public List<String> SelectedValues
        {
            get
            {
                String[] result = Text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                return new List<String>(result);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me in a multiline environment to my needs, so I've added to @Francisco Goldenstein's answer to enable this. What I needed was to autocomplete any 'word' in the TextBox and in any position/line. After minimal testing, this class seems to work well enough for me in a multiline TextBox. Hope it helps someone.

Main changes are in `UpdateListBox()` and `this_KeyDown()`, to deal with the 'current' word, i.e. the one just before the caret position, rather than the entire textbox contents.

Change the definition of `separators` in `UpdateListBox()` to suit your needs.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MultiLineAutoCompleteTextBox : TextBox
{
    private ListBox _listBox;
    private bool _isAdded;
    private String[] _values;
    private String _formerValue = String.Empty;
    private int _prevBreak;
    private int _nextBreak;
    private int _wordLen;

    public MultiLineAutoCompleteTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResetListBox();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        _listBox = new ListBox();
        KeyDown += this_KeyDown;
        KeyUp += this_KeyUp;
    }

    private void ShowListBox()
    {
        if (!_isAdded)
        {
            Form parentForm = FindForm();
            if (parentForm == null) return;

            parentForm.Controls.Add(_listBox);
            Point positionOnForm = parentForm.PointToClient(Parent.PointToScreen(Location));
            _listBox.Left = positionOnForm.X;
            _listBox.Top = positionOnForm.Y + Height;
            _isAdded = true;
        }
        _listBox.Visible = true;
        _listBox.BringToFront();
    }

    private void ResetListBox()
    {
        _listBox.Visible = false;
    }

    private void this_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateListBox();
    }

    private void this_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
            case Keys.Tab:
            case Keys.Space:
            {
                if (_listBox.Visible)
                {
                    Text = Text.Remove(_prevBreak == 0 ? 0 : _prevBreak + 1, _prevBreak == 0 ? _wordLen + 1 : _wordLen);
                    Text = Text.Insert(_prevBreak == 0 ? 0 : _prevBreak + 1, _listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    ResetListBox();
                    _formerValue = Text;
                    Select(Text.Length, 0);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                break;
            }
            case Keys.Down:
            {
                if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex < _listBox.Items.Count - 1))
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex++;
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            }
            case Keys.Up:
            {
                if ((_listBox.Visible) && (_listBox.SelectedIndex > 0))
                    _listBox.SelectedIndex--;
                e.Handled = true;
                break;
            }


        }
    }

    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Tab:
                if (_listBox.Visible)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            default:
                return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateListBox()
    {
        if (Text == _formerValue) return;
        if (Text.Length == 0)
        {
            _listBox.Visible = false;
            return;
        }

        _formerValue = Text;
        var separators = new[] { '|', '[', ']', '\r', '\n', ' ', '\t' };
        _prevBreak = Text.LastIndexOfAny(separators, CaretIndex > 0 ? CaretIndex - 1 : 0);
        if (_prevBreak < 1) _prevBreak = 0;
        _nextBreak = Text.IndexOfAny(separators, _prevBreak + 1);
        if (_nextBreak == -1) _nextBreak = CaretIndex;
        _wordLen = _nextBreak - _prevBreak - 1;
        if (_wordLen < 1) return;

        string word = Text.Substring(_prevBreak + 1, _wordLen);

        if (_values != null && word.Length > 0)
        {
            string[] matches = Array.FindAll(_values,
                x => (x.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower())));
            if (matches.Length > 0)
            {
                ShowListBox();
                _listBox.BeginUpdate();
                _listBox.Items.Clear();
                Array.ForEach(matches, x => _listBox.Items.Add(x));
                _listBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                _listBox.Height = 0;
                _listBox.Width = 0;
                Focus();
                using (Graphics graphics = _listBox.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _listBox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < 20)
                            _listBox.Height += _listBox.GetItemHeight(i);
                        // it item width is larger than the current one
                        // set it to the new max item width
                        // GetItemRectangle does not work for me
                        // we add a little extra space by using '_'
                        int itemWidth = (int)graphics.MeasureString(((string)_listBox.Items[i]) + "_", _listBox.Font).Width;
                        _listBox.Width = (_listBox.Width < itemWidth) ? itemWidth : Width; ;
                    }
                }
                _listBox.EndUpdate();
            }
            else
            {
                ResetListBox();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ResetListBox();
        }
    }

    public int CaretIndex => SelectionStart;

    public String[] Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _values;
        }
        set
        {
            _values = value;
        }
    }
}
```