# How to use Autosuggestion for two concatinated string seperated by '-' in combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, autosuggest

I am using combobox containing string like "01322-Abcdefg".
Assigning datatable as datasource to it.

I want to use autosuggestion in combobox.
I am using below code :
   combobox.DataSource         = datatable
   combobox.AutoCompleteMode   = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
   combobox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

But this will only suggest initial characters only ( eg : 01322 ),In my case i want user to suggest value even if he/she type next set of characters ( eg : Abcdefg ).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create and implement your own version of [IAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776292%28VS.85%29.aspx)?  It sounds like a common request so might be worth searching for existing solutions and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583480/autocomplete-that-looks-for-symbols-a-string-contains-rather-than-starts-with) first.