# How can I get C# textbox autocomplete to make suggestions based on contains rather than starts with?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a textbox in my C# Windows Forms application that has AutoCompleteMode set to AutoCompleteMode.Suggest, and my content source is a custom source.

My content source is custom, with the following values:

- Jim Smith
- Alice Walker
- Bob Walker
- Jeremy Smith

The content completion only appears to work by checking if the suggested items "start with" the value in the textbox.

For example:

```
text=J
```

Would result in the suggestions:

- Jim Smith
- Jeremy Smith

However, if the user types in

```
text=Walk
```

There are no results.

How can I get content completion to suggest the following?

- Alice Walker
- Bob Walker

Also, my end goal is to have a textbox where individuals can easy start typing email addresses.  The content of the autocompletion suggestions will be names + email addresses. For example:

```
- Jim Smith <jsmith@mycorp.com>
- Alice Walker <alice@some.email.com>
- Bob Walker <bob.walker@mycorp.com>
- Jeremy Smith <jeremys@foo.com>
```

Comment: @juharr thanks for fixing that, missed that in the preview.

Comment: Check out [A more useful auto-complete Textbox control](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2012/04/A-more-useful-auto-complete-Textbox-control.aspx)

Comment: See answer to this one (same question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox

Comment: Marked this as a dup of the question above, so others go directly to that question. (But I can't actually close it as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the built-in TextBox.

Reading the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBox.cs,577a143ad3bbfb97) reveals that the AutoComplete feature calls into the native function [SHAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759862(v=vs.85).aspx) to do it's job. That one does only prefix matching.

You would have to subclass TextBox and provide your own suggestion feature (or purchase one / find an open source one), to do this.