# How to explicitly set a Control's Event order

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox which I have used as an autocomplete list in my C# windows application, which has events like `MouseClick` and `Leave`. 
On `MouseClick`, I want to set the selected value to a textbox.
On `Leave`, I want to hide the listbox
Now, the problem is, when I click on a value in listbox, the `leave` event is fired and listbox gets hidden without setting the value. If I unset the `leave` event, things work as expected.

NOTE: The purpose of `Leave` event is to only hide the listbox when some other control is clicked. The autocomplete textbox is implemented using this reference: [WinForms | C# | AutoComplete in the Middle of a Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox)

Comment: To understand this better, if you hide it onLeave then how do you intent to click on it again?

Comment: You cannot tinker with event order, it is hard-coded in the OS and the control.  You can get code to run later pretty easily, but if you don't show your code then it is just a wild guess on how to use that feature appropriately.