# searching middle of string with autocomplete textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a textbox with a database table as an autocomplete source, I am filling the autocomplete string collection with the code below, it's working fine and suggestions are appearing as i type but this only suggests string which starts with what i'm typing, how can I get it to suggest strings that contains what i type.

Example, if I had a list of colors on my autocomplete and I type 'o' it would suggest colors like '**o**range' but also 'vi**o**let'

```
oracmd = New OracleCommand("Select column_name from table", oracon)
Dim ds As New DataSet
orada = New OracleDataAdapter(oracmd)
orada.Fill(ds, "list")
Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
     col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("column_name").ToString())
Next
TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms | C# | AutoComplete in the Middle of a Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox)

Comment: @Jaxi i'm not sure if i did something wrong or not. I tried the answer on that question, I even downloaded the original source and it was only working like a normal autocomplete. I typed 'o' in the textbox and it gave me 'one' only and not other results like 'two' and 'four'

Comment: In PL/SQl; Select column_name from table where upper(column_name) like '%O%;

Comment: @PrescottChartier I don't want to do that, I don't want to keep querying everytime the user types something, I just want get every possible data from the table, put it on a list or something and let the application handle the searching.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the dataset or datatable using LIKE.  For example:

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Select("column_name like  '%" & TextBox.Text & "%'")
```