# AutoComplete for second word in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autocomplete

I have a DataGridView and i have used AutoComplete in one of cell.But only first word can be searched using Autocomplete .I want second word also to be searched using AutoComplete. The data is being taken from database.

For example, db contains Coffee Powder,Tea,Salt Powder etc.

if i search Powder i want result as Coffee Powder and Salt Powder.Now i don't get any result if i  use second word for searching.

```
private void datagrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvdetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
            {
                string titleText = dgvdetails.Columns[2].HeaderText;
                if (titleText.Equals("Product Name"))
                {
                    TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
                    if (autoText != null)
                    {
                        autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = LoadAutoComplete(); //this method is below
                        autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                        autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection LoadAutoComplete()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = estimatesub.Searchproduct(num);

            AutoCompleteStringCollection stringCol = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
             //  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
                stringCol.Add(Convert.ToString(row[1]));
            }
            return stringCol;
        }
```

If my db contains Product Name:**Wheat,Sugar,Coffee Powder,Salt Powder**.
**My current result is:** if i search 'Wh' i get result Wheat,
if i search 'S' i get Sugar & Salt Powder,
if i search 'Su' i get Sugar,
if i search 'Po' i didn't get any result.

**Expected result :**
if i search 'Po' i want Salt Powder as result of Auto Complete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms | C# | AutoComplete in the Middle of a Textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox)

Comment: @LennartStooop No this wont work in grid

Comment: The autocomplete functionality that comes with `TextBox` and `ComboBox` works with prefix completion only, and it goes way down to the COM so its not possible to change that behavior. There is no other option than to roll your own I'm afraid

Comment: @LennartStoop could you please suggest another way to implement this other than autocomplete

Comment: What have you tried so far? You say the custom `Textbox` control I have linked earlier does not work in a grid: why? You might be able to make it work with a few modifications and if you'd get stuck you can post more detailed questions on here