# Enable full find-as-you-type combo box in WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms

The Windows Forms ComboBox control only offers partial find-as-you-type functionality - it only searches for the first letter. For example if you type "c" and "a", don't expect "California" to become selected - instead you'll land on a state starting with "a".

Somehow, perhaps through Firefox, I got used to being able to find items by typing out the first *several* letters of the item. This is particularly helpful if the items are not sorted in alphabetical order for one reason or another.

Is there a way to enable find-as-you-type for WinForms combo boxes that ideally doesn't involve a whole lot of coding or paying for third-party components?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-autocomplete

Answer (score 3):

The feature you are looking for is Autocomplete in ComboBox. Default behavior will not allow, what you want to do. I doubt you have to roll your own logic or inherit some one's work.

You can check following articles on CodeProject for the same.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16285/Auto-Complete-ComboBox

[image]

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3958/A-C-auto-complete-combo-box