# Override Winforms ComboBox Autocomplete Suggest Rule

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I'm trying to modify the behaviour of a Windows.Forms ComboBox so that the AutoComplete drop down displays items according to the rules I specify.

By default, if you use AutoComplete in a ComboBox, the rule that's followed is "string s is included in the drop down if( s.StartsWith( userEnteredTextInTheComboBox) )"  All I'm really interested in is substituting a new rule for the current one, but I can find no way to get at it.  (Specifically, I'd prefer s.Contains instead of s.StartsWith.)

I can kludge together a clumsy solution using two controls instead of one, but I'd really be happier with one that actually does what I want.

Update: I found essentially [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-autocomplete) after some more searching.  The answer supplied there suggests that using two controls to "fake it" is the way to go.

Answer (score 20):

I've had the same problem and looked for a quick solution.

Eventually I ended up writing it myself. It's a little dirty but it should not be hard to make it prettier if needed.

The idea is to re-build the combo list after every key press. This way we can rely on the combo's built-in interface, and we don't need to implement our own interface with a textbox and a listbox...

Just remember to set `combo.Tag` to `null` if you re-build the combo's options list.

```
private void combo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    comboKeyPressed();
}

private void combo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (combo.Text.Length == 0) comboKeyPressed();
}

private void comboKeyPressed() {
    combo.DroppedDown = true;

    object[] originalList = (object[])combo.Tag;
    if (originalList == null) {
        // backup original list
        originalList = new object[combo.Items.Count];
        combo.Items.CopyTo(originalList, 0);
        combo.Tag = originalList;
    }

    // prepare list of matching items
    string s = combo.Text.ToLower();
    IEnumerable<object> newList = originalList;
    if (s.Length > 0) {
        newList = originalList.Where(item => item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(s));
    }

    // clear list (loop through it, otherwise the cursor would move to the beginning of the textbox...)
    while (combo.Items.Count > 0) {
        combo.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    // re-set list
    combo.Items.AddRange(newList.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I did it but I should move this line "combo.DroppedDown = true;" in order to be the last line of the function. Otherwise it throws an exception when trying to remove the last item "combo.Items.RemoveAt(0);"

Comment: I receive an exception complaining about item cannot be removed when the data source property is set on the combo

Comment: @kuklei this cannot be done with a databound combo; populate items yourself manually like the answer does

Answer (score 1):

Before Windows Vista, the Autocomplete object [match candidates with prefix only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762479(VS.85).aspx), so you need to [cook your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301412.aspx).

If you need to reset the suggestion list when it is visible, [use IAutoCompleteDropDown::ResetEnumerator](http://jiangsheng.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!1BE894DEAF296E0A!732.entry).

Comment: How to write it in c# for a winforms

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ehsan. 
Just for reference.  I ended up with this.

```
    private void comboBoxIdentification_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxIdentification.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            comboBoxIdentificationKeyPressed(comboBoxIdentification, comboBoxIdentification.Text);
        }
    }

    private void comboBoxIdentificationKeyPressed(ComboBox comboBoxParm, string text )
    {
        comboBoxParm.DroppedDown = true;
        object[] originalList = (object[])comboBoxParm.Tag;
        if (originalList == null)
        {
            // backup original list
            originalList = new object[comboBoxParm.Items.Count];
            comboBoxParm.Items.CopyTo(originalList, 0);
            comboBoxParm.Tag = originalList;
        }

        // prepare list of matching items
        string s = text.ToLower();
        IEnumerable<object> newList = originalList;
        if (s.Length > 0)
        {
            newList = originalList.Where(item => item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(s));
        }

        // clear list (loop through it, otherwise the cursor would move to the beginning of the textbox...)
        while (comboBoxParm.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            comboBoxParm.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        var newListArr = newList.ToArray();
        // re-set list
        comboBoxParm.Items.AddRange(newListArr);
    }
```