# AutoComplete combobox (search anywhere within list, not just first letter )

Tags: c#

I have a combobox that fill with a datatable in form load.

```
Mycombo.DisplayMember = "FullName";
MyCombo.ValueMember = "ID";
MyCombo.DataSource = MyDattable;
```

And set `AutoComplateMode` to `SuggestAppend` and `AutoComplateMode` to List item.

When I insert a text into combobox it is fill with suggested that started with my text.

But I want it is fill wit all suggested that like mytext.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12791135/574632