# ListBox items as AutoCompleteCustomSource for a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have populated some items into a listbox using the datasource property. Now I need to set the AutoCompleteCustomSource for a textBox from the items listed in the listbox. Precisely, the DataSource for the ListBox and the AutoCompleteCustomSource for the textBox are same. How can I set the AutoCompleteCustomSource without using the for-loops?

.Net 2.0 only. No support for LINQ

Comment: I have used DataTable and DataViews to set the dataSource. It works.

Answer (score 1):

The `AutoCompleteStringCollection` takes only `string[]`, so it should be like this:

```
var cc = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
cc.AddRange(listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

Comment: ooh, good catch i did it like that because i didn't want to use foreach or for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your ListBox is a list of strings, you should be able to do this: *(untested)*

```
textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange((List<String>)listBox.DataSource);
```

Comment: this won't compile, the AutoCompleteStringCollection takes only string[]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question and answer seems to be appropriate. [autocomplete textbox on listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a8e31841-1ba9-4990-b0e3-bdee489555af/)

Another similar question [C# AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-autocomplete)