# Create a permanent autocomplete textbox in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to make an autocomplete textbox in c# so I set the **AutoCompleteMode** to *SuggestAppend* and set the **AutoCompleteSource** to *custom*,

It now works fine every time I start the exe but the problem is that it forgets the history when I close the exe and open it again.....so how can I make its history permanent?

Comment: Window form or web Application ?

Comment: Shyam , he said `everytime I open the exe` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your own `AutoCompleteCustomSource` .

Catch the `TextChanged`  event, save the new text to a file.

Your `AutoCompleteCustomSource` should read its values from that file.

You can read more on how to use `AutoCompleteCustomSource` here:

[ListBox items as AutoCompleteCustomSource for a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562989/listbox-items-as-autocompletecustomsource-for-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

You can save suggestions/history in text file and also update text file on each search
refer this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c#/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use all the three properties
"AutoCompleteCustomSource", "AutoCompleteMode" and "AutoCompletesource" on TextBox class.
then u will get the desired solution.