# Implementing Outlook email send to Autocomplete in a windows form

Tags: windows, outlook, outlook-addin, autosuggest

I'm trying to develop an outlook Add-in, when the addin button clicks it open a windos form. The windows form has a text field, In the text field when a name is typed it should show suggestion list as in outlook email "send to" field. I'm struggled with finding any source to read. Can anyone help :) ?

Comment: You can already do this in Outlook. When composing an email, type some letters in the `From` field and press Ctrl+K to bring up the Check Names dialog.

Comment: yeagh that's right, but I'm implementing an outlook add-in which opens a separate windows form. I want to implement the same behaviour in that form too. In the windows form there is also a text box to type the receivers name, so when a user types receivers name I need the autocomplete functionality there as same as when we have when sending an email from outlook.

Comment: What Outlook version? I think you can leverage the existing dialog box in your addin by simply calling it to display when you need it.

Comment: Outlook 2010, did you mean the "Address list dialog box". But requirenment is sugessioning contact info when type in a text box and display sugestions as in this link, http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, if I understand you correctly this should fulfill your requirements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176400(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I still need to complete this module. couldn't find any solution pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **SendTo list** is pulled from the autocompletion list cache and is handled differently based upon Outlook versions. In Outlook 2010, you can use the [**Suggested Contacts** folder](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/outlook/outlook-2010-autocomplete-cache-and-suggested-contacts), whereas in Outlook 2007 and below it is [contained in a hidden **NK2 file**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287623).

See [related link on how to manage the autocompletion cache](http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=1127).

Comment: Those are good stuff you have posted SilverNinja :). But I'm more struggled with how to show these suggestions as it is in outlook in a windows form.

Comment: Have you seen this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/800407/175679) regarding Winform Textbox Autocompletion?

Comment: Seems like this is the only options I have http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/multivalue-autocomplete-winforms-textbox-for-tagging/, thanks guys