# How to avoid insert text from autocomplete list to textBox until press Enter?

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, enter

I'm coding a textbox that auto suggest when I'm writing, but when autocomplete appear, if I press `Down`, my textBox1.Text change, therefore it call TextChanged function, and autocomplete list is being update.

I want while I press `Down`, the text dont change ultil I press `Enter`. Is any way to fix this issue?

Comment: you should've put a tag referring to the technology you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from implementing your own autocomplete, such as by overriding `OnTextChanged` and showing a list, the only options to control the behavior of autocomplete on a WinForms `TextBox` are given by the [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) property and the [enumeration of the same name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode). See [C# AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-sharp-autocomplete) for a related question.

Third party text boxes may have more options but I am not aware of any that do.

Answer (score 1):

Turn Off `Autocomplete` feature of `textbox`

`<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: sorry, I mean textBox in WinForm

Comment: Oops!.. I dont have much experience in win form, I am sure it should have a similar property.

Comment: CHECK OUT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx