# C# Textbox Autocomplete: How to provide custom 'matching' function?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I'm using C# TextBox with AutoComplete via a Custom Source of a collection of names, e.g. John Smith, Mary Jane, etc .. The problem is that if I type in 'John', I do see 'John Smith' in the dropdown. But if I start typing 'Smith', I no longer see 'John Smith' in the dropdown. I'd like to change this, and I think I would have to extend the TextBox class and provide my own function for matching data. I just don't know which TextBox function would need to be overwritten.

Secondly, another related issue I'd like to solve this is: The dropdown text is always left aligned. How can I make it center aligned ?

Comment: do you can use the `TextChanged` event and `string.Contain()` method?

Answer (score 1):

There is no *directly* way to do it because `AutoCompleteCustomSource` only allows prefix matching based on your input string.

From [`TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Use the AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and
>   AutoCompleteSource properties to create a TextBox that automatically
>   completes input strings by comparing the **prefix** being entered to the
>   prefixes of all strings in a maintained source.

Best option seems to override your [`OnTextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx) of your `TextBox`. The question below has a good example about it;

- [C# AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-sharp-autocomplete)